# Unable to do CRUD on tables involving foreign keys in django tastypie

Tags: tastypie

I am developing web api via django tastypie. But I got problems when doing CRUD api requests to models which involve foreign keys. Did a lot googling but couldn't find simple explaination of how to correct that.

Here are the codes:
**Models.py file:**

```
class LUserRole(models.Model):
    pk_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    role_value = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'l_user_role'

class TUsers(models.Model):
    pk_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    login_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fk_user_role_value = models.ForeignKey(LUserRole, db_column='fk_user_role_value', related_name = 'TUsers_fk_user_role_value')
    is_active = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 't_users'
```

and here is the other file:
**api.py file:**

```
class LUserRoleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:

        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = LUserRole.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user_roles'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        serializer = Serializer()
        always_return_data=True


class TUsersResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:

        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = TUsers.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        serializer = Serializer()
        always_return_data=True
```

**First problem:**
When I do a get request to api url, results are coming good, but excluding the foreign key columns.

**Second Problem:**
When I do a post request to api url, the following error is coming:
*"error_message": "Column 'fk_user_role_value' cannot be null",*

**Note:** The TUsers Model column fk_user_role_value is referring to role_value column of LUserRole Model.

Help me in getting rid of this problem.

Comment: Check for adding relationships. http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships

Comment: Thanks, but this problem has been solved.